# Begriff für das Weglassen von redundanten Adjektiven

Tags: adjective, terminology

Ich habe mal gehört, man soll beim Verfassen von Fachliteratur beispielsweise Pleonasmen vermeiden, also etwa Adjektive weglassen, wenn deren Gegenteil an dieser Stelle im Text sowieso keinen Sinn machen würde.

Beispiel: Man soll lieber "Leiche" statt "tote Leiche" schreiben, weil es klar ist, dass es das Gegenteil (eine "untote Leiche") nicht geben kann. Das Adjektiv "tot" ist hier also redundant.

Gibt es für die Regel/Konvention, dass man (zumindest bei bestimmten Texten) solche Redundanzen *vermeiden* sollte, einen Namen?

Comment: Ich befürchte, dass nein. Genausowenig, wie es einen Begriff für einen "Nicht-Verbrecher" gibt.

Comment: Kürze, Klarheit, Sparsamkeit, ...

Comment: Auch wenn es diese Unterteilung m.W. nicht gibt, würde ich die Tautologie als "unsachliches Stilmittel" beschreiben, was somit in einem formellen Text nichts zu suchen hat. In wissenschaftlichen Texten ist sogar generell von Stilmitteln abzusehen.

Comment: @userunknown Das ist zwar sowas ähnliches wie ein Gegenteil, aber kein richtiges. Man kann auch nicht gesetzestreu, aber trotzdem kein Verbrecher sein.

Comment: Das gilt selbstverständlich nicht nur beim Verfassen von Fachliteratur, sondern beim Schreiben jeglicher Texte.

Comment: Gibt es denn irgendwelche Pleonasmen, die sinnvoll sind?

Comment: @PaulFrost möglicherweise als Stilmittel. Ich könnte Dir beispielsweise mit exakter und präziser Genauigkeit den Unterschied zwischen einer Tautologie und einem Pleonasmus erläutern.

Comment: Auf Englisch sagt man knapp: [omit needless (words)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/5-writing-rules-destroyed-by-the-dictionary/omit-needless-words)

Answer (score 2):

Das würde ich schlichtweg

> Redundanzvermeidung

oder auch

> Ökonomie des Ausdrucks

nennen. Es ist grundlegendes Element guten Stils.

Ich empfehle hier wie stets: Ludwig Reiners: Stilfibel. Etliche Ausgaben seit ca. 1950. Unverändert aktuell, lehrreich und amüsant.

Comment: Der Reiners ist da vielleicht [nicht so ganz fein und rein gewesen](http://www.kritische-ausgabe.de/hefte/reich/stirnemann.pdf)?

Comment: @LangLangC. Danke! Sehr interessant!

Comment: schlichweg -> schlichtweg